# Format and align text in gojs chart

Tags: javascript, html, gojs

How can we format the first textblock (word 'success') to the right side of the shape circle and also second textblock should present at the bottom of the circle shape?

Attached the [fiddle link](http://jsfiddle.net/pandiyancool/s0zk5f34/77/) as well.

Helps much appreacited

gojs node template

```
myDiagram.nodeTemplate =
$(go.Node, "Auto", {
    movable: false
  },
  $(go.Panel, "Vertical",
    $(go.TextBlock, {
        margin: 5,
        font: '14px "Open Sans", sans-serif'
      },
      new go.Binding("text", "status")),

    $(go.Panel, "Auto", {
        background: "white"
      },
      $(go.Shape, "Circle", {
          strokeWidth: 4,
          margin: go.Margin.parse("10 5 10 5"),
          height: 75,
          width: 75,
          cursor: "pointer"
        },
        new go.Binding("fill", "color"), new go.Binding("stroke", "strokeColor")
      ),

      $(go.Panel, "Vertical",
        $(go.Picture, {
          source: "https://msdnshared.blob.core.windows.net/media/2017/05/icon.png",
          background: "white",
          width: 25,
          height: 25
        })
      )
    ),
    $(go.TextBlock, {
        margin: 5,
        font: '14px "Open Sans", sans-serif'
      },
      new go.Binding("text", "name"))
  )
);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've adapted your code a little bit:

```
myDiagram.nodeTemplate =
  $(go.Node, "Spot",
    {
      locationObjectName: "ICON", locationSpot: go.Spot.Center,
      movable: false
    },
    $(go.Panel, "Auto",
      {
        name: "ICON", background: "white",
        portId: "", cursor: "pointer",
        fromSpot: new go.Spot(0.5, 1, 0, 20)
      },
      $(go.Shape, "Circle",
        { strokeWidth: 4, width: 75, height: 75, margin: 5 },
        new go.Binding("fill", "color"),
        new go.Binding("stroke", "strokeColor")),
      $(go.Picture, "https://msdnshared.blob.core.windows.net/media/2017/05/icon.png",
        { width: 25, height: 25, background: "white" })
    ),
    $(go.TextBlock,
      {
        alignment: go.Spot.Bottom, alignmentFocus: go.Spot.Top,
        margin: 5, font: '14px "Open Sans", sans-serif'
      },
      new go.Binding("text", "name")),
    $(go.TextBlock,
      {
        alignment: go.Spot.Right, alignmentFocus: go.Spot.Left,
        font: '14px "Open Sans", sans-serif'
      },
      new go.Binding("text", "status"))
  );
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

use this syntax for each corner:

```
$(go.TextBlock, "0,0",     { alignment: new go.Spot(0, 0) }),
$(go.TextBlock, "0.5,0",   { alignment: new go.Spot(0.5, 0) }),
$(go.TextBlock, "1,0",     { alignment: new go.Spot(1, 0) }),
$(go.TextBlock, "0,0.5",   { alignment: new go.Spot(0, 0.5) }),
$(go.TextBlock, "0.5,0.5", { alignment: new go.Spot(0.5, 0.5) }),
$(go.TextBlock, "1,0.5",   { alignment: new go.Spot(1, 0.5) }),
$(go.TextBlock, "0,1",     { alignment: new go.Spot(0, 1) }),
$(go.TextBlock, "0.5,1",   { alignment: new go.Spot(0.5, 1) }),
$(go.TextBlock, "1,1",     { alignment: new go.Spot(1, 1) }),
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: I appreciate your efforts. Since I already had verified answer. I'm not going to use this and  also don't have that environment with me now. If anyone need in future, it will be helpful. Cheers!